# Refreshing contentflow javascript control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Im using this [contentflow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php) control and I'm in a bit of a rush here for a special requirement I have.

The casé is similar but not exactly like if you have laist of pics categories the user can selct by clicking. hwen user clicks the contentflow refreshes its content with the pics of the selected category.

I created a method for cleraing the contentflow like this:

```
    function ClearCoverflow() {
        //alert("starting clearing coverflow");
        var count = myNewFlow.getNumberOfItems();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            myNewFlow.rmItem(0);
        
    }
```

So my getPictures method becomes like this.

```
 function GetPictures() {
        $("#itemcontainer").html("");
        ClearCoverflow();
        var count = myNewFlow.getNumberOfItems();
        $("#itemcontainer").load('getItems.aspx', function () {
            //alert('Items where generated');
            AddPictures();
        });
```

AddPictures Method is analog to that of the example in the control web site but using jquery. The problem is that when this is executed, the caroussel appearance is lost and the images appears ina stack and does not cycle.

The website is a .net website MVC using VS2010 .net 4

Thanks a lot to you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized today that I was using the visibleItems option set to a fixed value. I removed it, and now it's working. There must be a bug in which when there is not enough items to fullfill the visibleItems value the contentflow colapses and becomes unresponsive in the way I explained.

You have to leave the option set as default, which is the squareroot of the number of items, which will always be fullfilled.

Hope it helps